# In the remastered Bard's Tale Trilogy, where are the Dreamspell words?

Tags: the-bards-tale

In inXile/Krome's remastered [Bard's Tale Trilogy](https://www.inxile-entertainment.com/bardstaletrilogy), the Dreamspell can't be used in BT2 Destiny Knight until

> you find five words in five dungeons, and say them in order at N9 E18 in Destiny stone.  Unlike similar quests, you have to actually visit the locations with the magic mouths.  They aren't spotted by SOSI, which makes them harder to find.

In the current version of the game, you can't access the room until the requirements are satisfied.

Where are the words found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order and locations are described by

> notes in Saradon's Workshop.

Word locations (thanks to [Icculus](https://steamcommunity.com/app/843260/discussions/0/1734342793781472427/?tscn=1543088950#c1742226629867652803) for 1/2/5):

> **First:** Grey Crypt, level 2, N11 E4, "If the spell of dreams you wield, safe you'll be behind its SHIELD."
>  **Second:** Maze of Dread, level 2, N9 E10, "Though enemies wear plate and sallet, a dream can crush them like a MALLET."
>  **Third:** Fanskar's Castle, N20 E21, "To the worthy I reveal, a dream to mend, a dream to HEAL."
>  **Fourth:** Oscon's Fortress, level 2, N16 E19, "Sword or mace or axe or pike, dream a dream to gain a STRIKE."
>  **Fifth:** Dargoth's Tower, level 3, N8 E13, "Illusions cunning and corrupt, a dream can shatter and DISRUPT."